Eslint error React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigate'
why I get this eslint error ?
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

I dont want to put the navigate it there because on every navigate function it would be called. I only want to call it when the auth state changes so I added the auth variable in the dependencies but eslint say I have to use navigate function also in dependencies but why ? and how can I solve this error ?
code:
import { Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import Login from "./pages/login"
import PasswordResetConfirm from "./components/PasswordResetConfirm/PasswordResetConfirm"
import useAuth from "./hooks/useAuth"
import { Index } from "./pages";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Holidays from "./pages/holidays";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!auth) {
      console.log(auth);
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, [auth]);
  return (
    <Routes>
      { !auth ? 
        <>
          <Route path="/reset_password" element={<PasswordResetConfirm />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </>
        :
        <>
          <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
          <Route path="/holidays" element={<Holidays />} />
        </>
      } 
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App



what happens when you add navigate to the dependency array? Did you try?

One simple way would be, to just ignore the rule for the line that is being shown other way would be to create a custom wrapper with useCallback
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

/**
 * Wraps the `navigate` function provided by `useNavigate` from
 * react router in a `useCallback` function to avoid redefinition every render
 */
export const useCustomNavigation = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  return useCallback(navigate, [navigate])
}

Now you can use navigate in your dependency array and  navigate will not be redefined every render so your useEffect should not re-run every navigate redefinition and the eslint warning will be gone.
Usage:
const navigate = useCustomNavigation()
// Your useEffect logic and other component logic here



Is this even necessary?  useNavigate is probably already returning a stable reference.  And if it isn't the useCallback is going to update anyhow and return a new reference every render anyhow.

It does not return "stable reference"  because it depends on pathname and other factors.   Not wrapping it in useCallback can cause unexpected behavior.

Your suggested changes are not going to quiet down the eslint warning.  Also, since navigate is in the dependency array for the useCallback the custom hook will return a different reference to navigate just as if you hadn't wrapped it in a useCallback.

The useCallback prevents allows you to put navigate in the dependency array without causing unnecessary re-renders

The dependency array of the useCallback serves the same purpose as the dependency array of useEffect.  When a value in the dependency array of a useCallback changes it returns a new reference.  In what you have provided, useCallback will return a new reference of navigate everytime navigate in it's dependency array updates.  When the useCallback returns a new reference, the dependnecy array of the useEffect will see that new reference and re-run the useEffect.  The code you have provided will behave no differently than the original code.

I'm not sure why you think useNavigate returns an unstable reference.  This code feels like a premature attempt at "optimization" based on developer assumptions.

This discussion can easily be resolved with a simple test if you put navigate in the dependency array without useCallback and count the re-renders vs using useCallback

Here's a code sandbox testing whether useCallback would do what is expected in the code you provided.  Open the console. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/clicker-trvzv6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A30%2C1
